# How to run command with preceding variable

Tags: powershell, environment-variables

(Sorry for the awful title, I obviously don't know I am talking about ;o)

I have a command which I assume is a Unix command

```
TSS_DEBUG=5667 code --user-data-dir ~/.vscode-debug/
```

What is the Windows PowerShell equivalent?

I tried

```
set TSS_DEBUG=5667; code --user-data-dir ~/.vscode-debug/
```

but it doesn't start a debugging version of VSCode.

Also, what is the variable `TSS_DEBUG` called? It's probably not an environment variable because it's local to the following command.

**Edit:** Thanks to [mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0), and the linked duplicate question, the **solution** is:

```
$env:TSS_DEBUG=5667; code --user-data-dir ~/.vscode-debug/
```

Comment: I hope the linked duplicate answers your question; let us know if you think it isn't a duplicate.

Comment: As for wording: you're looking for a way to set _environment variables_ that are scoped to a given external-program call (child process). That is, only that call (child process) will see these environment variables.

Comment: Thank you! I added the solution to the question for completeness. <)

Comment: Glad to hear it helped. Worth noting that, given that PowerShell currently does _not_ support command-scoped environment variables, `$env:TSS_DEBUG` lives on for the remainder of the caller's session, unless removed with `$env:TSS_DEBUG = $null`